# Need to check if if number is aggregated number or not

Tags: java, algorithm, optimization

A number "aggregated number" if this number has the following attribute:
just like the Fibonacci numbers
1,1,2,3,5,8,13.....

the digits in the number can divided into several parts, and the later part is the sum of the former parts.

like

```
112358, because 1+1=2, 1+2=3, 2+3=5, 3+5=8
122436 because 12+24=36
1299111210, because 12+99=111, 99+111=210
112112224, because 112+112=224
```

Need provide a function to check whether this number is aggregated number or not?

I wrote code but need to optimize it . Please Help

```
public class AggragetedNumber {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("1121325"));
}

static boolean isAggregatedNumber(String text) {
    int length = text.length() / 2;
    for (int i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j <= length; j++) {
            if (Match(i, j, text)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static boolean Match(int i, int j, String text) {
    String first = text.substring(0, i);
    String second = text.substring(i, i * 2);
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(first);
    buffer.append(second);
    while (buffer.length() < text.length()) {
        Integer x = (Integer.parseInt(first) + Integer.parseInt(second));
        String third = x.toString();
        buffer.append(third);
        first = second;
        second = third;
    }
    if (text.equals(buffer.toString()))
        return true;
    return false;
   }
 }
```

Comment: How about 111121325 - 11 + 1 = 12; 1 + 12 = 13; 12 + 13 = 25, but your program returns false

Comment: Thanks @BOND3 i just tested 3-4 cases any suggestions to improve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the key is to examine the correct permutations of the first two numbers:

**1)** length of the first number should not exceed half of the length of the entire number

**2)** length of the first & second number should not exceed length of the entire number minus length of the first number or the second, whichever is bigger (it can be further optimized though)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("111121325"));// true
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("122436"));// true
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("122437"));// false
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("1299111210"));// true
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("112112224"));// true
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("112012224"));// false
}

static boolean isAggregatedNumber(String text) {
    int length = text.length();
    for (int i = 1; i <= length / 2; i++) { // length of the first number should not exceed half of the length of the entire number
        for (int j = i + 1; j <= length - Math.max(i, j - i); j++) { // length of the first & second number should not exceed length of the entire number minus length of the first number or the second, whichever is bigger
            if (Match(i, j, text)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

static boolean Match(int i, int j, String text) {
    String first = text.substring(0, i);
    String second = text.substring(i, j);
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(first);
    buffer.append(second);
    while (buffer.length() < text.length()) {
        Integer x = (Integer.parseInt(first) + Integer.parseInt(second));
        String third = x.toString();
        buffer.append(third);
        first = second;
        second = third;
    }
    if (text.equals(buffer.toString()))
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an optimized version that doesn't repeatedly parse the numbers, and doesn't use a `StringBuilder`, making it fail faster on mismatches:

```
private static boolean isAggregatedNumber(String text) {
    for (int len1 = 1; len1 <= text.length() / 2; len1++) {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0, len1));
        for (int end2 = len1 + 1; end2 <= text.length() - len1; end2++) {
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(len1, end2));
            if (isAggregatedNumber(text, end2, num1, num2))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
private static boolean isAggregatedNumber(String text, int start, int num1, int num2) {
    for (;;) {
        final int    num3 = num1 + num2;
        final String str3 = Integer.toString(num3);
        final int    end3 = start + str3.length();
        if (end3 > text.length())
            return false;
        if (! text.substring(start, end3).equals(str3))
            return false;
        if (end3 == text.length())
            return true;
        start = end3;
        num1 = num2;
        num2 = num3;
    }
}
```

Or using tail-recursion, if you prefer:

```
private static boolean isAggregatedNumber(String text, int start, int num1, int num2) {
    final int    num3 = num1 + num2;
    final String str3 = Integer.toString(num3);
    final int    end3 = start + str3.length();
    if (end3 > text.length() || ! text.substring(start, end3).equals(str3))
        return false;
    if (end3 == text.length())
        return true;
    return isAggregatedNumber(text, end3, num2, num3);
}
```

Tested using extended test cases:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("00000000000000000"));   // true: 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("112"));                 // true: 1,1,2
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("113"));                 // false: 1,1,3
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("122436"));              // true: 12,24,36
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("122437"));              // false: 12,24,37
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("1123581321345589144")); // true: 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55,89,144 (fibonacci)
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("5611"));                // true: 5,6,11
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("1121325"));             // true: 1,12,13,25 
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("111121325"));           // true: 11,1,12,13,25
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("1299111210"));          // true: 12,99,111,210
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("11234512346"));         // true: 1,12345,12346
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("12345112346"));         // true: 12345,1,12346
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("112112224"));           // true: 112,112,224
    System.out.println(isAggregatedNumber("112012224"));           // false
}
```

---

***WARNING***

The loop optimizations of the two `for` loops in the first method prevents matching of `00010000034` (`0001,000003,4` aka `1,3,4`). Change both to `< text.length()` in order to support leading zeroes like that in the first two numbers.

Better yet, guard against leading zeros using:

```
private static boolean isAggregatedNumber(String text) {
    for (int len1 = 1; len1 < text.length() - 1; len1++) {
        int num1 = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(0, len1));
        for (int end2 = len1 + 1; end2 < text.length(); end2++) {
            int num2 = Integer.parseInt(text.substring(len1, end2));
            if (isAggregatedNumber(text, end2, num1, num2))
                return true;
            if (text.charAt(len1) == '0')
                break;
        }
        if (text.charAt(0) == '0')
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
```